# Did I make data recovery from my USB flash drive less likely?

Tags: linux, usb

I was using the `dd` command to copy my entire flash drive in 'blocks'. I was using the following:

```
dd if=/dev/sda bs=16M of=/filepath/filename
```

I was half asleep and I hit <kbd>enter</kbd> after `dd if=/dev/sda`, instead of hitting the <kbd>spacebar</kbd>.

Simply, since I don't know what hitting <kbd>enter</kbd> after `dd if=/dev/sda` did, so I would just like to know if I made recovery efforts for deleted/stolen files from my flash drive less likely.

I checked the flash drive and the amount of data present after I hit <kbd>enter</kbd> was the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dd if=/dev/sda`, with no other argument, will read `/dev/sda` 512 bytes at a time and copy its contents to standard out.

This won’t have changed anything on the USB drive, and won’t have affected potential recovery efforts.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you recommend an excellent recovery tool I can install on my linux system to recover deleted/stolen files from a usb flash drive that is FAT formatted? Or should I use a windows system to try to recover the files?

Comment: See [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec), it fits your requirements and is available packaged in most Linux distributions. For more advanced recovery, see also [Foremost](http://foremost.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Great, thank you Stephen.